# How to persist the android package name from config.xml to manifest file --cordova

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I have an app in the store where the package name has cap (com.RandRecruit).

Now , I an deploying a new version using IBM mobile first V8  and I have updated the config.xml. However, when I do a Cordova build I noticed in the manifest file the package name is converted to all lowercase.

How can I prevent cordova from changing the case for the name

Comment: What version of Cordova are you using? With Cordova 6.5.0 , I do not see this problem. The package name in the config.xml is what appears in the AndroidManifest.xml after build. If this is not what you are facing , be specific

Comment: Thanks.. I am using cordova 6.5.0 and in the manifest file,  the package name is always in lowercase. Although , I have mix case in the config.xml (android-packageName="com.RandRecrut"

Comment: I tried com.Test.project, com.TestProject.project. com.Test.Project and the package name always stays the one I entered. 
Are you using Windows? And whats the buildtools version?